# How to get most popular categories?

Tags: php, sql, oop, codeigniter

I need to show the most popular categories, which means the categories with the most courses. I have a databasase schema which includes:

```
tbl_categories:id, name ; tbl_category_courses: cat_id, course_id ; tbl_courses: id,name,description
```

My logic was this, to first get all the categories and after foreach category to count all the courses.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('categories')
                      ->limit($limit)
                      ->get();

    $data = array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $nr_of_courses = $this->db->select('*')
                                      ->from('course_categories')
                                      ->where('course_categories.category_id', $row->id)
                                      ->join('courses', 'courses.id=course_categories.course_id')
                                      ->count_all_results();

            $row->course_number = $nr_of_courses;
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
```

This is my code until now and all I can retrieve are the categories with how many courses each has, but I can not filter them. I need to show just the top 10.
Can someone give some directions and help. Also making the count query in a foreach loop I know is bad design, how can I improve this code because I will need to use it on the main application page and it needs to run smoothly.

Comment: have you tried putting a LIMIT on it?

Comment: a limit where? i don't really need a limit, i need to sort the result with the categories with the most $nr_of_courses I think...i do not think this can be achieved only from sql...or if it can please someone share

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in SQL, depending on your actual database type:

```
select top 10
  cat.name,
  count(distinct course_id) as cnt
from
  course_categories cc
join
  categories cat
    on cat.cat_id=cc.cat_id
group by
  cat.name
order by
 count(distinct cc.course_id) desc
```

I'm not familiar enough with (I'm assuming) linq, to write it using that format.
I hope that helps.